# Are there any light weight text editors (like Notepad) but with alternate background color?

Tags: .net-framework, html, windows, text-editors, notepad

I'm searching for my programming tool, i.e. a text editor. I like Notepad very much but I want a text editor with alternate background color for each line. Just like the background of the picture below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean **alternating** background color.  Might want to change that to relieve confusion.

Answer (score 2):

That's syntax highlighting. Try notepad++, http://notepad-plus-plus.org/.

Comment: notepad++ can't do it. What I mean is the white and grey color for each line and nothing to do with the text/syntax

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential solution for achieving it in Vim...

http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Alternate-Line-Highlighting-td1146116.html#a1146119